# Java compilation error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors

I have a code that is successfully compiled in Idea but fails to be compiled by `maven clean package`.
The code is

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class WebStatusMonitor {

    private ConcurrentMap<String, Double> load = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void handle(...) {
        ...
        snapshot.add(String.format("cpu: %s", load.getOrDefault("cpu", 0.)));
        ...
    }
```

And compilation fails with error

```
[ERROR] WebStatusMonitor.java:[121,66] cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getOrDefault(java.lang.String,java.lang.Double)
location: variable load of type java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>
```

I have included what I use (actually everything was included automatically by Idea) and this code is even compiled successfully in Idea. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your IDE uses java 8 and your maven is configured to use java 7.

The method [does not exist in java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) and [does exist in java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)

Comment: Don't understand this answer. ConcurrentHashMap seems to exist in java 7, no?

Comment: see the error message again... it is not about the class itself